# How to use trigger to perform addition from one table columns into another table column where id matches Sqlite

Tags: trigger, sqlite

Below is my SQLite Database with two tables.

```
import sqlite3


conn=sqlite3.connect('calc.db')
conn.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sum
        (id TEXT UNIQUE,
    name    TEXT,
    total   TEXT 
    )""")

conn.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS newtable
        (id TEXT,
    name    TEXT,
    num TEXT 
    )""")

conn.execute("""INSERT INTO sum(id, name, total) \
    VALUES('001', 'name1', '')""")
conn.execute("""INSERT INTO sum(id, name, total) \
    VALUES('002', 'name2', '')""")
#
conn.execute("""INSERT INTO newtable(id, name, num) \
    VALUES('001', 'name1', '1000')""")
conn.execute("""INSERT INTO newtable(id, name, num) \
    VALUES('002', 'name2', '2000')""")
conn.execute("""INSERT INTO newtable(id, name, num) \
    VALUES('001', 'name1', '4000')""")


conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

`Sum table` has `unique id` and `newtable` `id` is not unique. I want to perform addition in `sum table` in `total column` that should be taken the addition value from newtable column when inserting and if id matches. Hoe to do. My columns are text type. If not posible in TEXT type i can change it into integer but it is better to continue in TEXT type if possible.  How to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a trigger to your python script

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sum
>         (id TEXT UNIQUE,
>     name    TEXT,
>     total   TEXT 
>     )
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS newtable
>         (id TEXT,
>     name    TEXT,
>     num TEXT 
>     )
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO sum(id, name, total) 
>     VALUES('001', 'name1', '');
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO sum(id, name, total) 
>     VALUES('002', 'name2', '');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER sum_after_insert
>    AFTER INSERT ON newtable
> BEGIN
>   UPDATE sum SET total = total + NEW.num WHERE id = NEW.id;
> END;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO newtable(id, name, num) 
>     VALUES('001', 'name1', '1000');
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO newtable(id, name, num) 
>     VALUES('002', 'name2', '2000');
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO newtable(id, name, num) 
>     VALUES('001', 'name1', '4000');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM sum;
> ```
>
> ```
> id  | name  | total
> :-- | :---- | :----
> 001 | name1 | 5000 
> 002 | name2 | 2000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=23f5330f12bdd8dbcb43cfaf3d3b4ce4)*

Comment: Its working perfect for me. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER 
AFTER INSERT
ON newtable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE sum 
    SET total = total + NEW.num
    WHERE name = NEW.name;
END
```

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=fe6660bf19fe28041a96ef6488976228)

Comment: The name column is not unique. If i change the name to id in WHERE clause its working perfect for me. Thank you.